# What differentiates a Canon standard zoom from an ultra-wide angle zoom?

Tags: lens, canon, zoom, ultra-wide

I was checking the Canon website and found that the EF-S 15-85mm f/3.5-5.6 IS USM lens is a "standard" zoom lens, whereas the EF 17-40mm f/4L USM is described as an "ultra-wide" Zoom.

Is there anything else other than focal length which makes a lens ultra-wide angle or standard zoom?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The EF-S 15-85 can be used only on APS-C cameras, where it will have an *full frame equivalent* focal length of 15 * 1.6 to 85 * 1.6 = 24-136mm. As such, it's approximately equivalent to a "normal" zoom on a full frame camera.

The EF 17-40 *when mounted on a full frame camera* has the stated focal lengths (17-40mm) and is an ultrawide zoom. However, if you mount it on a APS-C camera, its equivalent focal lengths will be 27-64mm and it could be considered to be a normal zoom.

Answer (score 4):

The lenses differ in the sensors they're built for.

EF-S lenses are built for APS-C sensor formats (canon rebel series, 60D, 7D), while EF lenses are for both APS-C and full-frame (6D, 5D's, 1D).

In 35mm equivalents, the EF-S 15-85mm acts as a 24-136mm lens, which is indeed a standard zoom lens, even if a bit long (24-70 can be considered the quintessential standard zoom range). In the same vein, to achieve the same range the EF 17-40mm offers but in APS-C format, you should find yourself something in the vicinity of a 10-25mm. Canon conveniently provides a EF-S 10-22mm lens, although without fixed aperture.

Comment: The EF-S 10-22mm f/3.5-4.5 USM lens has been available from Canon since 2006.

Answer (score 2):

**The terms *Ultra-Wide* and *Standard* apply more to the resulting field of view in an image than the actual focal length of the lens used to produce the image.** Field of view is a result of both the focal length of the lens and the size of the recording media. In large format photography a 50mm lens is considered *Wide Angle*. In 35mm photography it is considered *Normal*. With sensors such as those APS-C size and smaller it is considered *Telephoto*. In all three cases *the description is based on the **field of view of the resulting image.***

For lenses such as the EF-S 15-85mm f/3.5-5.6 that may only be used on an APS-C camera body **the resulting images have the same angle of view** as a 24-135mm lens would have on a camera with a 35mm-film sized "full frame" sensor. Thus it is considered a *Standard zoom* because of the **field of view of the photos that can be taken with it.** Likewise, if the EF 17-40mm f/4 lens is mounted on an APS-C body, *the resulting field of view* is equivalent to a 28-65mm zoom lens on a full frame camera. In this case it would also be considered a *Standard Zoom Lens.* Canon also makes an EF-S 10-22mm f/3.5-4.5 lens that is considered an *Ultra-Wide* zoom lens on APS-C cameras.